# Generate random text files at a specific speed in C#

Tags: c#, performance, random, generator, rate

I have created a C# console app which continuously creates text files with randomly created strings. Time (in minute) is given as an input to the app and it runs for that number of minutes to generate continuous text files. I understand that the amount of data generated will vary depending upon the processor speed and other configurations. My machine is able to generate a total of 25 mb of data in text format in 1 minute.

Now, my question is, can I control the rate of data generated per minute if given as another input to the app through my code?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var start = DateTime.Now;
int bytesSaved=0;
double desiredSpeed = (25*1024*1024)/60;

while(true)
{
  int latency = bytesSaved/(DateTime.Now-start).TotalSeconds - desiredSpeed;
  if(latency>0) 
    {          
      Thread.Sleep(100);
      continue;
    }

  bytesSaved +=SaveDataChunk(latency);     

}
```

Comment: I just typed it here with no testing, should give a direction

Comment: Thank you so much. I modified the code to calculate the latency in time and passed it to thread.sleep method which allowed me to exactly sleep for the required milliseconds. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only able to generate 25MB in a minute, and it's just random strings, then you've got something else to think about - you should easily be able to do orders of magnitude more than that in a minute.

But as far as controlling that, only way I can think of is to manually keep a timer running, and keep track of how much you're writing in how much time, to auto-calculate your rate as you're going - then sleep appropriately if necessary once you compute how fast you're going, vs. how fast you want to go.

It won't be perfect, but you should be able to make a best guess, and continually adjust your sleep time based on past performance.

Comment: Thanks Joe for the answer. The problem is i dont know which machine/configuration it will run on, so i cannot make a best guess of the performance. That would be another tedious job of making a performance decision engine based on the machine configuration.

Comment: @sridam.g Then this answer is *exactly* what is needed: **"auto-calculate your rate as you're going - then sleep appropriately"**. That is, a "target rate" is set, and the program does its best to follow the schedule by waiting (in a busy loop or timer) as appropriate. It's similar to how games limit FPS so say, 60/second. Note that the algorithm *doesn't* know about the machine configuration - only how long it *has taken* to write the previous output.

Comment: You'd have to calculate performance yourself, not assume anything. For example, in your loop, after 100 iterations or so, see how much time has elapsed. Let's say 100 iterations takes 1 second, but you want to see 1,000 iterations in one minute. Then you're going way too fast, and need to throttle down to 900 iterations in 59 seconds for the remainder of your minute. Sleep for 50ms betweeen each iteration for the next hundred, and see where you're at then. Keep throttling every n number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could do one of two things; if you want to control the mb's of the data then have the user pass in an int which you use to control the length of the string written to the file. Another option would be to use a sleep. You could have the user pass in a sleep value and then you could sleep for that amount of time between each write.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First option would be the input. Sleep time will not be given as an input. Length of string in each line of the text file is of a particular format. it cannot be changed or controlled. I have to control the rate at which the strings are being written to the files.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a timer and create a file every N seconds.